# Creating a list of items where each has a value assigned

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am working on a method in Python that counts the number of times a word is used in an input set (natural language), and I am hoping to, in order:

- Create a list of the words  (excluding common ones like 'I', 'you', 'a')
- Put them into a list
- Assign them each a value `x` (number of times used)
- Sort them by `x`
- Return the list sorted

Example:

Input:

```
"one two two two three three three"
```

Output:

```
["three", "two", "one"]
```

The trouble is I don't know how to create lists where you can assign values to the items.

Comment: Time to start studying `dict`ionaries. :-) (and maybe `collections.Counter`)

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the stopwords, as I don't know which method you want to use, but for counting, you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

example = "one two two two three three three"

count = Counter(example.split())

print(count.most_common())
# [('two', 3), ('three', 3), ('one', 1)]
```

It even bundles in the count for you, but if you don't want it:

```
print([tup[0] for tup in count.most_common()])
# ['two', 'three', 'one']
```